# How to put two different tasks in Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, paint

I have following code. in this code i have an image which moves from left to right and a button which has an event. but i want to put these both tasks in Threads. so that it can work properly. the problem with this code is that button event does not work until it reaches to the right most point.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class MyImage extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
   static int xPixel = 20;
   Image myImage, offScreenImage;
   Graphics offScreenGraphics;
   JPanel p = new JPanel();
   Button btn = new Button("bun");
   JFrame f = new JFrame();


   public MyImage()
   {
      myImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("mywineshoplogo.jpg");
      setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
      this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setVisible(true);
      add(p);
      p.add(btn);
      moveImage();
      btn.addActionListener(this);
   }

   public void update(Graphics g)
   {
      paint(g);
   }

   public void paint(Graphics g)
   {
      int width = getWidth();
      int height = getHeight();
      if (offScreenImage == null)
      {
         offScreenImage = createImage(width, height);
         offScreenGraphics = offScreenImage.getGraphics();
      }
// clear the off screen image  
      offScreenGraphics.clearRect(0, 0, width + 1, height + 1);
// draw your image off screen  
      offScreenGraphics.drawImage(myImage, xPixel, 10, this);
// draw your image off screen  
// show the off screen image  
      g.drawImage(offScreenImage, 0, 0, this);
// show the off screen image  
   }

   void moveImage()   //left to right move
   {
  Thread hilo = new Thread() {

  public void run() {
 try {

      for (int i = 0; i < 530; i++)
      {

         xPixel += 1;
         repaint();
        // then sleep for a bit for your animation  
         try
         {
            Thread.sleep(4);
         } /* this will pause for 50 milliseconds */

         catch (InterruptedException e)
         {
            System.err.println("sleep exception");
         }
      }
  } //try
  catch (Exception ex) {
      // do something...
  }
  }
  };
  hilo.start();
   }

/*   void moveimg()   // right to left move
   {
      for (int i = 529; i > 0; i--)
      {
         if (i == 1)
         {
            moveImage();
         }
         xPixel -= 1;
         repaint();
// then sleep for a bit for your animation  
         try
         {
            Thread.sleep(40);
         } // this will pause for 50 milliseconds 

         catch (InterruptedException e)
         {
            System.err.println("sleep exception");
          }
      } 
   } */     

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
   {
      try
      {
         if (ae.getSource() == btn)
         {
            p.setBackground(Color.RED);
         }
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
         System.out.println("error");
      }
   }

   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      MyImage me = new MyImage();
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you try to comment out `clearRect` in your `paint` method? Of course, the image will me smeared over the screen, but at least you can verify that the background doesn't get red for max 4 milliseconds and will then be overwritten by the paint method...

Comment: What's the purpose of offScreenImage? If you aim at double buffering, this is useless because Swing does it internally for you already. Btw, you should not extend `JFrame` but rather extend `JPanel`, override `paintCOmponent` rather than `paint`, and set that panel as the content pane of your JFrame. Also, always invoke the super-method of all `paintXXX` methods or you will see visual glitches

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you are about to write `Thread.sleep` in your GUI code, stop yourself and introduce a  task scheduled on Swing's `Timer`. This is exactly what you need with your code: schedule each update as a separate scheduled task on `Timer`. `Timer` is quite simple and straightforward to use, see for example [this official Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).